# Why github ask me password of git user instead of password of my publickey?

Tags: git, github, ssh

[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJXkv.png)

Yesterday I updated github's fingerprint, but after that I cannot use ssh to connect to github.com anymore.

I've tried to regenerate key and added it to github. But it still doesn't work.

`ssh -vT git@github.com`:

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/23097/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [223.75.236.241] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/23097/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:rEmlJenVMSL5GVemSY0Gk8WGw6B4ege4J85M+vup8R0
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/23097/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/23097/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 2 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:0k6E5hrjYHm9AdhrRF5Rp6Rb+Gxx4Ln+01Uf626Y9nA agent
debug1: Will attempt key: hscivitasv@gmail.com ED25519 SHA256:f5kZ2jUz0HAWNkB3juN3lhxNy+MMpBCTgJtXC0vBx/U agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:0k6E5hrjYHm9AdhrRF5Rp6Rb+Gxx4Ln+01Uf626Y9nA agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: hscivitasv@gmail.com ED25519 SHA256:f5kZ2jUz0HAWNkB3juN3lhxNy+MMpBCTgJtXC0vBx/U agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@github.com's password:
```

I have `id_ed25519` and `id_ed25519.pub` in my .ssh folder, and I'm sure I've added it to github's ssh keys. Plz any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem today...

In my case, on the first time that I tried to push to GitHub today, it warned me with "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED".
Thus I updated GitHub fingerprint, and on the second push it prompted me to input "git@github.com's password"

After several trail, I found I can't even connect to GitHub.com in web browser without using proxy, I don't know if it is the same with you.

Then I manually set GitHub's IP address in hosts... and everything goes back to normal...

Comment: Much appreciate, That works. Although a little weird...

Comment: Hi MxLi, how can I manually set Github's IP address in hosts? could you give me a detailed guide? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output carefully, you will see that your SSH client has offered a key to the server, but the server has declined it.  It has then tried a bunch of default private key filenames ... which presumably don't exist.  Finally it has switched to asking for a password.

So ... the most likely explanations are:

- You didn't copy the *public* key to the GitHub settings page.
- You didn't copy the *entire* key.
- You forgot to click the `Add Keys` button after pasting it.
- You didn't add the private key to your shell's ssh-agent before attempting to connect.  (Doing that will prompt for your private key's passphrase.)

Note: A public key doesn't have a password / passphrase.  The passphrase is on the private key.

<sup>(What would be the point of a passphrase to protect a public key?  It is supposed to be readable by anyone / everyone who wants to use it.)</sup>

For reference: ["Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account"](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Comment: from debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/23097/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:0k6E5hrjYHm9AdhrRF5Rp6Rb+Gxx4Ln+01Uf626Y9nA agent

Comment: I know.  I saw that.  I even mentioned it in the first sentence of my answer!!

Comment: But the `SHA256..` stuff is the same as what i have in github's ssh and gpg keys setting page. See: https://imgur.com/IIhaxdw. so i'm confused why github declined it.

Comment: Please read the rest of my answer.  I have given you 4 possible reason why it might happen.   It seems like it might be the 4th reason.   (Note: being sure you did something doesn't mean you actually did it, or that you did it correctly ...)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I've read these 4 possible reasons.
1 & 2: I've copied entire public key.

3: I'm sure I clicked it.

4: I've used `ssh-add` command to add it, and it actually prompted me to input password.

Comment: If you've checked all of those things and it still doesn't work, I am out of ideas ... unless ... are you using the wrong GitHub username?